# How to make dual monitor not mirrored at startup?

Tags: multiple-monitors

In 18.04, every time I boot into Ubuntu my dual monitor get into mirrored configuration. Then I should make it sleep and log in again to make it back to normal (correspond to monitors.xml configuration).

Thing like this doesn't happen in 16.04. I don't know why, anybody could help?

Comment: Are you using the same Unity interface in 18.04 that you used in 16.04 or are you signing on with Gnome interface instead? Click the gear icon next to `Sign On` button  to verify.

Comment: my 16.04 is ubuntu gnome so my 18.04 is  obviously signing on as gnome